# How to save time information into an SQLite file in Xamarin?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I have a PopUp that contains two TimePicker and an Editor controls. The user selects start/end time using those TimePickers and then enters their text in the Editor control. I want to save the information entered in those TimePickers and Editor to an SQLite file. I created a folder named  Model, then I added a class for Model:

```
namespace MReport.Models
{
    public class TimeActivity
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement] public int ID { get; set; }
        public string TimeStamp1 { get; set; }
        public string TimeStamp2 { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I created a folder named Data and added a class as below:

```
namespace MReport.Data
{
    public class ActivityDatabase
    {
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;

        public static readonly AsyncLazy<ActivityDatabase> Instance = new AsyncLazy<ActivityDatabase>(async () =>
        {
            var instance = new ActivityDatabase();
            CreateTableResult result = await Database.CreateTableAsync<TimeActivity>();
            return instance;
        });

        public ActivityDatabase()
        {
            Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);
        }

        public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(TimeActivity item)
        {
            if (item.ID != 0)
            {
                return Database.UpdateAsync(item);
            }
            else
            {
                return Database.InsertAsync(item);
            }
        }

    }
```

The AsyncLazy class is as below:

```
 public class AsyncLazy<T>
    {
        readonly Lazy<Task<T>> instance;

        public AsyncLazy(Func<T> factory)
        {
            instance = new Lazy<Task<T>>(() => Task.Run(factory));
        }

        public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> factory)
        {
            instance = new Lazy<Task<T>>(() => Task.Run(factory));
        }

        public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter()
        {
            return instance.Value.GetAwaiter();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            var unused = instance.Value;
        }
    }
```

XAML code for PopUp:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">
        <Label Text="From Time:" Padding="2,2,0,0" TextColor="Black"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
        <TimePicker x:Name="Time_Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Time="{Binding TimeStamp1}" />
        <Label Text="To Time" Padding="2,2,0,0" TextColor="Black"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
        <TimePicker x:Name="Time_End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Time="{Binding TimeStamp1}" />
        <Label Text="Your Activities:" Padding="2,2,0,0" TextColor="Black" />
        <Editor x:Name="editor_value" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="140" Text="{Binding Text}" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Add" Clicked="Button_Clicked_2" />
    </StackLayout>
```

And finally, code for the button saves data into db3 file:

```
   async void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string timeString01 = DateTime.Today.Add(Time_Start.Time).ToString(Time_Start.Format);
        string timeString02 = DateTime.Today.Add(Time_End.Time).ToString(Time_End.Format);
        string time = string.Join("__", timeString01, timeString02);
        string total = string.Join(",", time, editor_value.Text);
        Dismiss(total);

    //The code below saves data into SQLite
    var timeActivity = (TimeActivity)BindingContext;
    ActivityDatabase database = await ActivityDatabase.Instance;
    await database.SaveItemAsync(timeActivity);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

The problem is that when I press the button to save data, a runtime error occurs and the app goes into break mode:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
> Please help me.

Comment: first, why are you saving DateTime values as strings?  SQLIte.net supports DateTime types.  Second, the stack trace of the exception should show you exactly which line causes the exception

Comment: I changed those two TimeStamp1 and TimeStamp2 variables into DateTime type. But the problem still exists. I don't know where to find stack trace of the exception in visual studio 2019. Can you please guide me?

Comment: add some basic exception handling to your code.  Or step through it the debugger until you hit the exception.  Or read any of the thousands of posts about how to use the VS debugging tools.

Comment: I found the line. In `SaveItemAsyn` method, `if (item.ID != 0)` causes exception. how can I fix it?

Comment: figure out why `item` is null (I'm assuming `item` is the problem) and fix it.  Most likely your cast of `BindingContext` is failing

Comment: are you **positive** that `BindingContext` is a `TimeEntry`?

Comment: I used casting (TimeActivity) because I have defined ID, TimeStamp1, TimeStamp2, and Entry in TimeActivity class. The sample project has used this method too.

Comment: is the `BindingContext` of that page a `TimeActivity`?  That is a yes or no question.  If the answer is "no" then casting will fail and return null.

Comment: Yes, it is a type of `TimeActivity`. But I have not used ID in XAML code.

Comment: based on the code you've post the most likely cause is that `BindingContext` is not a `TimeActivity`.  If you want to post more code to disprove that theory please do

Comment: How can I set BindingContex in my page? `<xct:Popup xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="MReport.popup01"
             Size="300,400"
             BindingContext="">`

Comment: `this.BindingContext = new SomeVMClass();`

Comment: Thank you very much.  Solved.  Can you please tell me where can I find my db3 file while I'm in debugging mode in Visual Studio?

Comment: whatever path you used to create it

Comment: I have defined the file name as `ReportData.db3` and used the following code to determin the path: `var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
                return Path.Combine(basePath, DatabaseFilename);` but I cannot find such a path in windows.

Comment: if you are using Android you will need to extract the files from the device/simulator.  For iOS simulator the files will be in the MacOS filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved by determining `BindingContex` in code behind for the button as below:

```
this.BindingContext = new TimeActivity();
```

Jason helped me to solve this problem.